# weird result when using linq to set value

Tags: c#, linq

I was trying to use LINQ to set some values in my list, but somehow the following code will not have the value set.

```
class Person
{
    public string name;
    public Person(string name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }
}

List<Person> people = new List<Person>() { new Person("a"), new Person("b") };
people.Select(x => { x.name = "c"; return x; });
foreach (Person person in people)
{
    Console.WriteLine(person.name);
}
```

However, if I add ToList() after calling select method, the values will be set:

```
List<Person> people = new List<Person>() { new Person("a"), new Person("b") };
people.Select(x => { x.name = "c"; return x; }).ToList();
```

Even stranger, if I call ToList() on a separate line, it won't work either:

```
List<Person> people = new List<Person>() { new Person("a"), new Person("b") };
people.Select(x => { x.name = "c"; return x; });
people.ToList();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, it's always a good idea to not produce LINQ queries that produce side effects.  Your entire goal here is to produce a side effect in a `Select()` statement.

The reason that `ToList()` causes this to have an effect is that LINQ queries don't execute until you enumerate the results.  `ToList()` causes the query results to be enumerated fully (in order to build the list).  If you were to write:

```
foreach (Person person in people.Select(x => { x.name = "c"; return x; }))
{
```

You'd see that the effects occur, as the foreach iterates through the results.

That being said, the "proper" way to write values using LINQ is to filter, then change later:

```
var peopleToEdit = people.Where(p => string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(p.Name));
foreach(var person in peopleToEdit)
    person.Name = "Foo"; // Assign like so
```

Basically, the query should be side-effect free, and then use normal control flow for actually editing the values.

Comment: +1 for the answer, and +1 for the advice against `Select`s with side-effects, but alas I have only one +1 to give.

Answer (score 0):

Use the .Where clause.

```
    List<Person> people = new List<Person>() { new Person("C"), new Person("b") };
    var something = people.Where(x => x.name == "C");
    foreach(var x in something)
    {

    }
```

This was Tested

Comment: Maybe, but it doesn't really address the question in any way.

Answer (score 0):

```
people.Where(p => string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(p.Name)).ToList().ForEach(cc=>cc.Name="Foo");
```